# Extract date (yyyy-mm-dd) from a timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a timestamp format, 2019-12-12T16:10:02+11:00 and want to only extract the date value 2019-12-12  in PostgreSQL.

I tried `SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', TIMESTAMP '2019-12-12T16:10:02+11:00');`

the value return as 2019-12-12 00:00:00.0, any way can completely get rid of the time portion?

Comment: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', TIMESTAMP '2019-12-12T16:10:02+11:00')::DATE

Comment: @JonasMetzler: why the date_trunc()? Casting to a date is more than enough

Comment: Of course. You can also remove this. The question for me sounded like the author want to use DATE_TRUNC, but maybe I just understood the question wrong.